# How to open a apple maps application with directions from my ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, maps, direction, apple-maps

My aim is to open a map application from ios application with directions, I am able to open maps application but it is not showing directions, i have written the code as follows

```
 NSString *mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=Newyork"];
            NSURL *myurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mystr];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
```

Can any one please help me how figure out how to pass parameters to this url and any other?

Comment: please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605879/iphone-app-show-direction-using-map

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mean taking the user to the maps application based on two points, then you can do it like this:

Create an NSURL that looks like this:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f"];
```

You plug in your starting address and destination (in lat. and long.) appropriately.
Tell your application to open the URL

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

It should take you to the maps application automatically!

Answer (score 23):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate =    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.location.latitude,self.location.longitude);

//create MKMapItem out of coordinates
MKPlacemark* placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem* destination =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];
if([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:)])
{
    //using iOS6 native maps app
    if(_mode == 1)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking}];

    }
    if(_mode == 2)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

    }
    if(_mode == 3)
    {
        [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeTransit}];

    }

} else{

    //using iOS 5 which has the Google Maps application
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%f,%f", self.location.latitude, self.location.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

Comment: Where is the `_mode` variable coming from?

Comment: Your own variable to choose what you want :)