# Swift - encode URL

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode

If I encode a string like this:

```
var escapedString = originalString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

it doesn't escape the slashes `/`.

I've searched and found this Objective C code:

```
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                        NULL,
                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

Is there an easier way to encode an URL and if not, how do I write this in Swift?

Answer (score 730, accepted):

#### Swift 3

In Swift 3 there is `addingPercentEncoding`

```
let originalString = "test/test"
let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
print(escapedString!)
```

Output:

> test%2Ftest

#### Swift 1

In iOS 7 and above there is `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`

```
var originalString = "test/test"
var escapedString = originalString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
println("escapedString: \(escapedString)")
```

Output:

> test%2Ftest

The following are useful (inverted) character sets:

```
URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet  "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLHostAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/<>?@\^`{|}
URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet  "#%/:<>?@[\]^`{|}
URLPathAllowedCharacterSet      "#%;<>?[\]^`{|}
URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet     "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLUserAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/:<>?@[\]^`
```

If you want a different set of characters to be escaped create a set:
Example with added "=" character:

```
var originalString = "test/test=42"
var customAllowedSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}").invertedSet
var escapedString = originalString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(customAllowedSet)
println("escapedString: \(escapedString)")
```

Output:

> test%2Ftest%3D42

Example to verify ascii characters not in the set:

```
func printCharactersInSet(set: NSCharacterSet) {
    var characters = ""
    let iSet = set.invertedSet
    for i: UInt32 in 32..<127 {
        let c = Character(UnicodeScalar(i))
        if iSet.longCharacterIsMember(i) {
            characters = characters + String(c)
        }
    }
    print("characters not in set: \'\(characters)\'")
}
```

Comment: And if I want to add the equal sign too?

Comment: Add a custom character set, I added an example.

Comment: Is no one else completely flabbergasted at how long this code is to do this? I mean that method name is already hell of long, even without choosing the allowed character set.

Comment: No, I favor understandability over short terse naming. Autocomplete takes the pain out. `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters()` leaves little doubt about what it does. Interesting comment considering how long the word: "flabbergasted" is.

Comment: stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) Does not encode all character properly Bryan Chen's answer is a better solution.

Comment: @JulioGarcia either pick a character set based on the portion of the URL you are using or create a custom character set that matches your needs. Look at the `customAllowedSet` example.

Comment: Thanks Zaph, I just noticed that function it's been deprecated in iOS 9

Comment: @zaph What about `&`?

Comment: @AkashKava pick a character set that meets your needs of use `charactersInString:` to create a custom character set.

Comment: @zaph I added `&` to character set of  `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` and I got each character encoded. Checked with iOS 9, looks like buggy, I went with @bryanchen's answer, it works well !!

Comment: Why is Apple putting this method in the String class and not on NSURL?

Comment: That the method takes a string and returns a string is my best guess.

Comment: And of course, they've cleaned up the API a bit now. For example:

    let myEncodedString = myString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

Comment: Your code doesn't encode `!` and some other special chacacters... why?

Comment: Apple supplies several charactersets directed toward URL encoding. If you need to encode a different characterset than those supplied by Apple use the example of `customAllowedSet`.

Comment: The answer below that uses `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem` is much cleaner IMO.

Comment: I used `CharacterSet(charactersIn: "=&").inverted` Thanks @zaph

Comment: Is it possible to back to test/test after conversion?

Comment: all swift code is unnecessarily verbose. It's as bad as .NET library built-ins. too many primitive types too, but that's off topic. In js it's just encodeURIComponent, I don't know why the default in swift is to give you too many options, just encode for standard HTTP protocols and have separate parms for things you'd never use.

Answer (score 105):

You can use URLComponents to avoid having to manually percent encode your query string:

```
let scheme = "https"
let host = "www.google.com"
let path = "/search"
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "Formula One")


var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = scheme
urlComponents.host = host
urlComponents.path = path
urlComponents.queryItems = [queryItem]

if let url = urlComponents.url {
    print(url)   // "https://www.google.com/search?q=Formula%20One"
}
```

---

```
extension URLComponents {
    init(scheme: String = "https",
         host: String = "www.google.com",
         path: String = "/search",
         queryItems: [URLQueryItem]) {
        self.init()
        self.scheme = scheme
        self.host = host
        self.path = path
        self.queryItems = queryItems
    }
}
```

---

```
let query = "Formula One"
if let url = URLComponents(queryItems: [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query)]).url {
    print(url)  // https://www.google.com/search?q=Formula%20One
}
```

Comment: This answer needs more attention, as there are issues with all of the other ones (though to be fair they may have been best practice at the time).

Comment: Sadly, `URLQueryItem` does not always encode correctly. For example, `Formula+One` would be encoded to `Formula+One`, which would be decoded to `Formula One`. Therefore be cautious with the plus sign.

Comment: @Sulthan having a string "Formula+One" should be encoded to "Formula+One". This is because "+" is in the set of [Reserved Characters](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2), which is included in the set of "pchar" which constitutes the query component. If the decoding would yield "Formula One" using URLComponents, then something is wrong ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper This is a bit more complex than you think. Yu are quoting from URI spec but this is about URL, which is a special case. There are actually (at least) two URL specs with some conflicts. The URI spec itself says _"If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be percent-encoded before the URI is formed."_ This is obviously incorrect for `URLComponents` because a plus sign in URL-encoded output represents a space.

Comment: @Sulthan In the [URL spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org) an URL query is defined as an ASCII string (with only rudimentary constraint checks in the serialiser and parser). To figure out the rules for parsing and serialising of a query which is a list of key value pairs, we need to look at  [x-www-form-urlencoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Besides having some guidelines here, the spec itself says about x-www-form-urlencoded: "[this] format is in many ways an aberrant monstrosity, the result of many years of implementation accidents ..."  ;)

Comment: @Sulthan As far I have tested, URLComponents behaves correctly according the URI spec and according the rules defined in x-www-form-urlencoded: a plus sign "+" will not be encoded. In URLComponents, decode is the correct inverse to encode.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper To put it simply. When you want to pass a phone number with international prefix, e.g. `+1....` to a GET request, you compose your query using `URLComponents` and then your server interprets the incoming `+` as a space, something is wrong.  Foundation implementation works differently than the implementation in any other language (compare `encodeURIComponent` in javascript). Since this is the only implementation of URL-encoding in the library, I consider it a bug.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem. In the x-www-form-urlencoded, the decoding algorithm is NOT the inverse to the encoding function. It would, if the decoding would not unconditionally convert a "+" into a space, but just take it as is. Currently it MUST do this. Alternatively, it would be the inverse if the encoder would 1. _unconditionally_ convert spaces to "+" AND 2. percent encode "+".  IMHO, this is a bummer. Note: 1. is optional. 2. is not possible unless redefining the query percent-encode set.

Answer (score 94):

### Swift 4 & 5

To encode a parameter in URL I find using `.alphanumerics` character set the easiest option:

```
let urlEncoded = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
let url = "http://www.example.com/?name=\(urlEncoded!)"
```

Using any of the standard Character Sets for URL Encoding (like `.urlQueryAllowed` or `.urlHostAllowed`) won't work, because they do not exclude `=` or `&` characters.

Using `URLComponents` also doesn't work properly because it does not escape the `+` character.

**Note** that by using `.alphanumerics` it will encode some characters that do not need to be encoded (like `-`, `.`, `_` or `~` -– see *2.3. Unreserved characters* in RFC 3986). I find using `.alphanumerics` simpler than constructing a custom character set and do not mind some additional characters to be encoded. If that bothers you, construct a custom character set as is described in [How to percent encode a URL String](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-percent-encode-a-url-string/), like for example:

```
// Store allowed character set for reuse (computed lazily).
private let urlAllowed: CharacterSet =
    .alphanumerics.union(.init(charactersIn: "-._~")) // as per RFC 3986

extension String {
    var urlEncoded: String? {
        return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: urlAllowed)
    }
}

let url = "http://www.example.com/?name=\(value.urlEncoded!)"
```

**Warning:** The `urlEncoded` parameter is force unwrapped. For invalid unicode string it might crash. See [Why is the return value of String.addingPercentEncoding() optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558933/why-is-the-return-value-of-string-addingpercentencoding-optional). Instead of force unwrapping `urlEncoded!` you can use `urlEncoded ?? ""` or `if let urlEncoded =  urlEncoded { ... }`.

Comment: .aphanumerics did the trick, thank you! All the other character sets didn't escape the &'s which caused problems when using the strings as get parameters.

Comment: Works on Swift 5.X and iOS14

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I wasted a bunch of time trying the other top answers which don't work with = characters.

Comment: Why `.aphanumerics` instead of `.urlHostAllowed`? From the name, it sounds like it should encode `&`... Or is there another concern / advantage?

Comment: Using `.urlHostAllowed` does not escape `=` or `&` characters, as written in the answer. Feel free to try it yourself.

Answer (score 51):

Swift 5:

```swift
extension String {
    var urlEncoded: String? {
        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.alphanumerics.union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "~-_."))
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet)
    }
}

print("\u{48}ello\u{9}world\u{7}\u{0}".urlEncoded!) // prints Hello%09world%07%00
print("The string ü@foo-bar".urlEncoded!) // prints The%20string%20%C3%BC%40foo-bar
```

Comment: You need to include ` ` (space) in the string of characters

Comment: You also need to include ^

Comment: This is wrong. `let originalString = "\u{48}ello\u{9}world\u{7}\u{0}"` becomes `"Hello\tworld\u{07}\0"`. E.g. control characters or a tabulator are not escaped.

Answer (score 50):

#### Swift 3:

```
let originalString = "http://www.ihtc.cc?name=htc&title=iOS开发工程师"
```

**1. encodingQuery:**

```
let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

**result:**

```
"http://www.ihtc.cc?name=htc&title=iOS%E5%BC%80%E5%8F%91%E5%B7%A5%E7%A8%8B%E5%B8%88"
```

---

**2. encodingURL:**

```
let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

**result:**

```
"http:%2F%2Fwww.ihtc.cc%3Fname=htc&title=iOS%E5%BC%80%E5%8F%91%E5%B7%A5%E7%A8%8B%E5%B8%88"
```

Comment: I used first solution but I want to my text back, like iOS开发工程师.

Comment: Using `urlHostAllowed` for encoding query parameters in incorrect because it won't encode `?`, `=` and `+`. When encoding query parameters, you have to encode parameter name and value separately and correctly. This won't work in a general case.

Comment: @Sulthan.. Did you find any solution / alternative for `urlHostAllowed`

Comment: @Bharath Yes, you have to build a character set by yourself, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39767927/669586 or just use `URLComponents`.

Comment: URLComponents don't encode the `+` char too. So the only option is to do it manually: `CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+"))`

Comment: it worked with hrebrew language(RTL language) url too

Answer (score 32):

**Swift 4 & 5 (Thanks @sumizome for suggestion.  Thanks @FD_ and @derickito for testing)**

```
var allowedQueryParamAndKey = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
allowedQueryParamAndKey.remove(charactersIn: ";/?:@&=+$, ")
paramOrKey.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedQueryParamAndKey)
```

**Swift 3**

```
let allowedQueryParamAndKey =  NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.remove(charactersIn: ";/?:@&=+$, ")
paramOrKey.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedQueryParamAndKey)
```

**Swift 2.2** (Borrowing from Zaph's and correcting for url query key and parameter values)

```
var allowedQueryParamAndKey =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ";/?:@&=+$, ").invertedSet
paramOrKey.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowedQueryParamAndKey)
```

**Example:**

```
let paramOrKey = "https://some.website.com/path/to/page.srf?a=1&b=2#top"
paramOrKey.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedQueryParamAndKey)
// produces:
"https%3A%2F%2Fsome.website.com%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage.srf%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2%23top"
```

This is a shorter version of Bryan Chen's answer.  I'd guess that `urlQueryAllowed` is allowing the control characters through which is fine unless they form part of the key or value in your query string at which point they need to be escaped.

Comment: I like the Swift 3 solution, but it does not work for me in Swift 4: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'urlQueryAllowed' is a get-only property".

Comment: @MariánČerný just make the CharacterSet mutable (with `var`) and then call `.remove` on it in a second step.

Comment: I believe this and most other solutions have issues when applying the method twice, eg when including an URL with encoded params in another URL's parameters.

Comment: @FD_ do you know or do you just have a hunch?  Can you experiment with it and post back?  Would be good to include this info if so.  Thank you.

Comment: @AJP I just tested all your snippets. Swift 3 and 4 work fine, but the one for Swift 2.2 doesn't properly encode %20 as %2520.

Comment: Swift 4 solution works for me in July of 2020, using Swift 5

Comment: Thanks @FD_ .  Sorry I've only just seen this now.  Any easy fix you can think of?

Comment: In Swift 5, with `.urlQueryAllowed`, seems only "&" is not removed by default

Answer (score 17):

### Swift 4:

It depends by the encoding rules followed by your server.

Apple offer this class method, but it don't report wich kind of RCF protocol it follows.

```
var escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
```

Following this useful [tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html) you should guarantee the encoding of these chars for your parameters:

- $ (Dollar Sign) becomes %24
- & (Ampersand) becomes %26
- + (Plus) becomes %2B
- , (Comma) becomes %2C
- : (Colon) becomes %3A
- ; (Semi-Colon) becomes %3B
- = (Equals) becomes %3D
- ? (Question Mark) becomes %3F
- @ (Commercial A / At) becomes %40

In other words, speaking about URL encoding, you should following the [RFC 1738 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738).

**And Swift don't cover the encoding of the + char for example**, but it works well with these three **@  :  ?** chars.

So, to correctly encoding each your parameter , the `.urlHostAllowed` option is not enough, you should add also the special chars as for example:

```
encodedParameter = parameter.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
```

Hope this helps someone who become crazy to search these informations.

Comment: ampersand not working at all. what happen ?

Answer (score 15):

Everything is same

```
var str = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    nil,
    "test/test",
    nil,
    "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue
)

// test%2Ftest
```

Comment: You didn't `.bridgeToOvjectiveC()` second argument and didn't get "Cannot convert the expression's type 'CFString!' to type 'CFString!'" ?

Comment: @Kreiri Why it is needed? Both playground and REPL are happy with my code.

Comment: Mine aren't :/ (beta 2)

Comment: This is a better answer as it encodes the & correctly.

Answer (score 12):

### Swift 4.2

A quick one line solution. Replace `originalString` with the String you want to encode.

```
var encodedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]{} ").inverted)
```

[Online Playground Demo](https://repl.it/repls/DentalWarmTechnician)

Comment: This worked thanks: you can check and try decode and encode results on. https://www.urldecoder.org

Comment: I don't think this is a correct implementation. For example `let originalString = "\u{48}ello\u{9}world\u{7}\u{0}"` gets encoded to `"Hello\tworld\u{07}\0"`. E.g. control characters or a tabulator is not escaped.

Comment: Worked for me, converted the + to %2B and other characters also. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is working for me in **Swift 5**. The usage case is taking a URL from the clipboard or similar which may already have escaped characters but which also contains Unicode characters which could cause `URLComponents` or `URL(string:)` to fail.

First, create a character set that includes all URL-legal characters:

```swift
extension CharacterSet {

    /// Characters valid in at least one part of a URL.
    ///
    /// These characters are not allowed in ALL parts of a URL; each part has different requirements. This set is useful for checking for Unicode characters that need to be percent encoded before performing a validity check on individual URL components.
    static var urlAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet {
        // Start by including hash, which isn't in any set
        var characters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "#")
        // All URL-legal characters
        characters.formUnion(.urlUserAllowed)
        characters.formUnion(.urlPasswordAllowed)
        characters.formUnion(.urlHostAllowed)
        characters.formUnion(.urlPathAllowed)
        characters.formUnion(.urlQueryAllowed)
        characters.formUnion(.urlFragmentAllowed)

        return characters
    }
}
```

Next, extend `String` with a method to encode URLs:

```swift
extension String {

    /// Converts a string to a percent-encoded URL, including Unicode characters.
    ///
    /// - Returns: An encoded URL if all steps succeed, otherwise nil.
    func encodedUrl() -> URL? {        
        // Remove preexisting encoding,
        guard let decodedString = self.removingPercentEncoding,
            // encode any Unicode characters so URLComponents doesn't choke,
            let unicodeEncodedString = decodedString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlAllowedCharacters),
            // break into components to use proper encoding for each part,
            let components = URLComponents(string: unicodeEncodedString),
            // and reencode, to revert decoding while encoding missed characters.
            let percentEncodedUrl = components.url else {
            // Encoding failed
            return nil
        }

        return percentEncodedUrl
    }

}
```

Which can be tested like:

```swift
let urlText = "https://www.example.com/폴더/search?q=123&foo=bar&multi=eggs+and+ham&hangul=한글&spaced=lovely%20spam&illegal=<>#top"
let url = encodedUrl(from: urlText)
```

Value of `url` at the end: `https://www.example.com/%ED%8F%B4%EB%8D%94/search?q=123&foo=bar&multi=eggs+and+ham&hangul=%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80&spaced=lovely%20spam&illegal=%3C%3E#top`

Note that both `%20` and `+` spacing are preserved, Unicode characters are encoded, the `%20` in the original `urlText` is not double encoded, and the anchor (fragment, or `#`) remains.

**Edit:** Now checking for validity of each component.

Answer (score 5):

**For Swift 5 to endcode string**

```
func escape(string: String) -> String {
    let allowedCharacters = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ":=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}").inverted) ?? ""
    return allowedCharacters
}
```

**How to use ?**

```
let strEncoded = self.escape(string: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_e2a1b9bf2d996cbd9875b80612ed9aa4")
print("escapedString: \(strEncoded)")
```

Answer (score 4):

Had need of this myself, so I wrote a String extension that both allows for URLEncoding strings, as well as the more common end goal, converting a parameter dictionary into "GET" style URL Parameters:

```
extension String {
    func URLEncodedString() -> String? {
        var escapedString = self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        return escapedString
    }
    static func queryStringFromParameters(parameters: Dictionary<String,String>) -> String? {
        if (parameters.count == 0)
        {
            return nil
        }
        var queryString : String? = nil
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let encodedKey = key.URLEncodedString() {
                if let encodedValue = value.URLEncodedString() {
                    if queryString == nil
                    {
                        queryString = "?"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queryString! += "&"
                    }
                    queryString! += encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue
                }
            }
        }
        return queryString
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This does not encode the '&' sign. Using a '&' in a parameter will f*** up the querystring

Comment: This is wrong, it does not encode `&` or `=` in parameters. Check my solution instead.

Answer (score 3):

This one is working for me.

```
func stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormData(plusForSpace: Bool=false) -> String? {

    let unreserved = "*-._"
    let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
    allowed.addCharactersInString(unreserved)

    if plusForSpace {
        allowed.addCharactersInString(" ")
    }

    var encoded = stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowed)

    if plusForSpace {
        encoded = encoded?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
    }
    return encoded
}
```

I found above function from this link: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-percent-encode-a-url-string/.

Answer (score 2):

`let Url = URL(string: urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? "")`

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers worked for me. Our app was crashing when a url contained non-English characters.

```
 let unreserved = "-._~/?%$!:"
 let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumeric()
     allowed.addCharacters(in: unreserved)

 let escapedString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed as CharacterSet)
```

Depending on the parameters of what you are trying to do, you may want to just create your own character set. The above allows for english characters, and `-._~/?%$!:`

Answer (score 2):

What helped me was that I created a separate `NSCharacterSet` and used it on an UTF-8 encoded string i.e. **textToEncode** to generate the required result:

```
var queryCharSet = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
queryCharSet.remove(charactersIn: "+&?,:;@+=$*()")
    
let utfedCharacterSet = String(utf8String: textToEncode.cString(using: .utf8)!)!
let encodedStr = utfedCharacterSet.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharSet)!
    
let paramUrl = "https://api.abc.eu/api/search?device=true&query=\(escapedStr)"
```

Comment: After 4 days of struggling this piece of code really helped. Thanks Mohsin. You are champ. Good luck and keep coding. Thanks once again. please upvote coders.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4.2**

Sometimes this happened just because there is space in slug OR absence of URL encoding for parameters passing through API URL.

```
let myString = self.slugValue
                let csCopy = CharacterSet(bitmapRepresentation: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.bitmapRepresentation)
                let escapedString = myString!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: csCopy)!
                //always "info:hello%20world"
                print(escapedString)
```

NOTE : Don't forget to explore about `bitmapRepresentation`.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have an issue with Strings like this `%5B×××%5D` (where some parts were already encoded).

Took me an hour to realize that it can be easily solved with this:

```
extension String {
    var decodeThenEncodeURL: String {
        removingPercentEncoding?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? self
    }
}
```

- input: `https://www.google.com/search?q=%5B×××%5D`
- output: `https://www.google.com/search?q=%5B%C3%97%C3%97%C3%97%5D`

Answer (score -1):

This is better and more authoritative. it quotes from Almofire URLEncodedFormEncoder.swift

```
extension CharacterSet {
    /// Creates a CharacterSet from RFC 3986 allowed characters.
    ///
    /// RFC 3986 states that the following characters are "reserved" characters.
    ///
    /// - General Delimiters: ":", "#", "[", "]", "@", "?", "/"
    /// - Sub-Delimiters: "!", "$", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", ";", "="
    ///
    /// In RFC 3986 - Section 3.4, it states that the "?" and "/" characters should not be escaped to allow
    /// query strings to include a URL. Therefore, all "reserved" characters with the exception of "?" and "/"
    /// should be percent-escaped in the query string.
    public static let afURLQueryAllowed: CharacterSet = {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="
        let encodableDelimiters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")

        return CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(encodableDelimiters)
    }()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

version:**Swift 5**

```
// space convert to +
let mstring = string.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
// remove special character
var allowedQueryParamAndKey = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
allowedQueryParamAndKey.remove(charactersIn: "!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]%")
return mstring.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedQueryParamAndKey) ?? mstring
```

Comment: You say Swift 5 but then you use NSCharacterSet instead of CharacterSet, which is a weird choice. Also you're first replacing spaces with a + character but then in the list of characters to remove we see a space, so the first operation is redundant.

Comment: use NSCharacterSet instead of CharacterSet，that because refer to other answers.@EricAya

Comment: `+` can be used to represent a space, but existing instances of `+` need to be properly escaped. This answer is an example of what not to do.

Answer (score -4):

**Swift 5**
You can try .**afURLQueryAllowed** option if you want to encode string like below

```
let testString = "6hAD9/RjY+SnGm&B"
let escodedString = testString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .afURLQueryAllowed)
print(escodedString!)
```

//encoded string will be like **en6hAD9%2FRjY%2BSnGm%26B**

Comment: downvoted because of afURLQueryAllowed is releated on third party Alamofire.