# How to URL Encode full DateTime in Swift

Tags: ios, datetime, swift, url-encoding

Hi I am trying to make a request to the Google Calendar API V3 and setting a minDate value.  According to the Google API documentation the date needs to be encoded. see: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Looking at the explanations given in this Question: [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url) I can party achieve this by using the following:

```
// todayString = "2014-11-10T23:15:25+1300"
var escapedTodayString:NSString! = todayString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
```

This however only encodes part of the string and the output is: **2014-11-10T23%3A15%3A25+1300**
This fails in the request.  The output I require is: **2014-11-10T22%3A38%3A48%2B1300**

When I make the request using the desired output it works as expected.

How can I achieve this level of encoding please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by following code. Which removes "+" from the allowed characters

```
var todayString = "2014-11-10T23:15:25+1300"

var characters = NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet().mutableCopy() as NSMutableCharacterSet

characters.removeCharactersInString("+")

var escapedTodayString:NSString! = todayString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(characters)
```

Comment: Great help Shuo thanks!  I also had to add the characters.removeCharactersInString(":") to get rid of the colons.