# Replace characters to url acceptable format [iOS/SWIFT]

Tags: ios, string, swift, special-characters

i want to look up cities for a weather application.
iOS [Swift]
The webservice has a built in accuracy search, so i just have to pass the string to the url.

```
var searchedCity:String = searchBar.text
searchedCity = searchedCity.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

The 2nd line will change the space characters to underscore characters:

" " -> "_"  example: ( Los Angeles to Los_Angeles )

Thats fine, but how can i replace all the special characters to english characters, or URL acceptable characters.

example characters to replace: áéíöóőüúű to aeiooouuu

Or, if there is any other way to force the keyboard to use only english characters, please let me know.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at url encoding/decoding?

More details on that can be found here

[Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)