# Escaping backslash in Swift

Tags: string, swift, escaping

I'm sending regular expressions to CloudKit as a String value and it doesn't seem to like it, replacing `\\`by `\`. However, once I'm getting this value from my app I would like to retransform it in its original form, with `\\`instead of `\`.

I don't know how to manage this kind of escaped characters in Swift because I cannot even set a String with a `\` in my code but I'm still able to manage them when getting them from CloudKit. Here is an example of String:

```
var onlyOneBackslash: String = valueFromCloudKit
print(onlyOneBackslash) // booking\.com
```

How to escape the backslash to transform `booking\.com` into `booking\\.com`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The double backslash exists only in your code, it is a convention of the compiler. It never exists in the string itself, just in the Swift code.

If you want a double backslash in the string you need to have four backslashes in your code. Or use a String method to replace single backslashes with double backslashes.

Code example:

```
let originalString = "1\\2"
print("originalString: \(originalString)")
let newString = originalString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)
print("newString: \(newString)")
```

Output:

```
originalString: 1\2  
newString: 1\\2
```

Comment: What to do if you want the "1\2" value to a string variable ?

Comment: If you need to include a "\" in a string just escape it "\\". See [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285) and scroll to *Special Characters in String Literals*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zaph, actually the problem is I wanted to send "\/Date(1310669017000)\/" as a parameter to some web-service if i escape this with \\ it will send that parameter as "\\/Date(1310669017000)\\/"  not "\/Date(1310669017000)\/". I thing escape only works with print().

Comment: There are two things here. 1. putting a "\" in a string, several characters need escaping when created as literals in code. 2. URL encoding certain characters for URLs. There can be some overlap. For URL encoding see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url/24552028#24552028).

Comment: Actually i have to send "\/Date(1310669017000)\/" parameter as POST i am not encoding this in a URL.

Comment: @ShahidAslam Do you get any solution for the problem I am also doing the same and can't find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version

```
let originalString = "1\\2"
print("originalString: \(originalString)")
let newString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "\\\\")
print("newString: \(newString)")
replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "\\\\")
```

Output:

```
originalString: 1\2  
newString: 1\\2
```