Escaped Double Quote in Swift breaking JSONDecoder decode
If you open a play ground and paste this code, you'll notice that the decoded object is nil. The JSON object [{"transcript":"A person might say, \"Hello\"."}] passes any linter successfully but it seems like the default JSON decoder in Swift has an issue with the escaped double quotes (\") in the transcript. To make sure, in my playground when I remove the two escaped double quotes from the string, it works fine.
var testData2 = """
[{"transcript":"A person might say, \"Hello\"."}]
"""
struct TranscriptModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let transcript : String
}
typealias Transcripts = [TranscriptModel]
let decodedResponse1 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Transcripts.self, from: Data(testData2.utf8))
print(decodedResponse1)

It seems like a bug in Swift's JSON decoder? Is there a work around so that I can show double quotes in my json string?
If used by itself within your code, swift recognizes the escaped double quote and works perfectly by showing the " symbol as you can see in the picture below

This is causing a much bigger issue in my application, but I just broke down the error to where it's reproducible in an easy way
I am sharing an example of the same JSON string working in JavaScript too


You need to use two back slashes in a swift string

@JoakimDanielson I tried using two back slashes, but prints it out as A person might say, \"Hello. Swift still displays one of those back slashes

That’s just how it’s being presented in the console.

@JoakimDanielson So you're saying that the rules for a standard JSON object are different in Swift? And the API should return a JSON object with \\" instead of \" ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119119/escaping-backslash-in-swift

Also note, that in your JS example, the variable named "json" is not JSON, it is a JavaScript literal. JSON is closely based on JavaScript literal syntax (but not a strict equivalent, but it is not important). Important is that the "True JSON" must be a "string" that you feed into JSON.parse in JS or the JSONDecoder's instance method in your Swift sample.

@myf the link you shared is to escape a backslash, I'm just trying to escape a double quote "

@Saamer no, you need to have a string value with a backslash followed by a double quote in the resulting string. But there is no other way to "put a literal backslash into a (not raw) string literal" than to use the double backslash, since in the string literal the backlash is a special ("control"/"escape") character there. You don't need to "escape" the double quote in the Swift three-double quote-fenced string literal unless there are three of them adjacent (just like you haven't escaped the "outer" quotes), you'd need to escape them in simple inline string literal.

Think the simplest example: let's say you need to have text foo "bar" baz encoded in JSON: "foo \"bar\" baz". The string literal of that encoded value would be then "\"foo \\\"bar\\\" baz\"". The tripple-quote literal removes the necessity to escape double quotes for you, much like using single outer qotes in our example: '"foo \\"bar\\" baz"'. This is exactly your case. Is it more clear now?

In a JSON file, a string containing the " character must escape it as \". In Swift, however, a string containing the \ character must escape it as \\.
Your example works if the JSON string provides \\", where \\ is required by Swift and translates to \ and \" is required by the JSON syntax.
var testData2 = """
[{"transcript":"A person might say, \\"Hello\\"."}]
"""

You can alternatively avoid escaping \ by using a raw string literal as follows:
var testData2 = #"""
[{"transcript":"A person might say, \"Hello\"."}]
"""#


So the rules for a standard JSON object are different in Swift? And the API should return a JSON object with \" instead of " only for my Swift application?

No, according to docs that's the basics rules for string literals: backslash is a special character allowing you to 1) escape quotes (\") 2) insert line feeds, tabs and backslash itself (\n\t\\ ) 3) insert Unicode sequences (\u{1234}), refer to: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#Special-Characters-in-String-Literals

According to the doc you shared, no where does it say you need to use two backslashes in swift. In fact if you take the code in a playground/app and try that, it will actually show an extra backslash in the output @myf

[...] the doc you shared, no where does it say you need to use two backslashes in swift. Read again, please: • The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash), \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), " (double quotation mark) and ' (single quotation mark)

@Saamer the same rule applies to Javascript too. The code snippet you posted as an image is not equivalent to what you want to achieve in Swift. This is https://godbolt.org/z/a9PeWr5ax. You need to escape \\ too in Javascript strings.
