# Swift: String can't be nil, so why can stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters be nil?

Tags: string, swift

I'm relatively new to Swift and I've been wrapping my head around optional variables. Here's the issue I've run into:

```
func escape(s: String) -> String
{
    if s == nil
    {
        return ""
    }

    return s.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
}
```

The compiler complains that:

`Value of type 'String' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed`

This is in reference to the `if s == nil` line. If I remove the if statement line and just have the return value line, I get the error:

`Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'`

I see in the docs that stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters returns a String? parameter. I don't understand why this isn't forced to be a String? Since a String can't be nil, I can't pass nil to this function, so how would it return nil?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33558933/292145

Answer (score 2):

- You defined the parameter `s` as non optional `String`.
  A non optional type can never be nil, that's why the compiler complains.
  Just remove the checking for `nil`.
- You defined the return type as a non optional `String`.
  Either you have to unwrap the result value to conform to the type

  ```
  func escape(s: String) -> String
  {
    return s.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
  }
  ```

  or change the return type to an optional

  ```
  func escape(s: String) -> String?
  {
    return s.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Not a minute after posting I read deeper into the docs. stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters CAN return a nil value, even given a non-nil value. From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters

> Return Value Returns the encoded string, or nil if the transformation
>   is not possible.
>
> Discussion UTF-8 encoding is used to determine the correct percent
>   encoded characters. Entire URL strings cannot be percent-encoded.