# Swift:Value of Type String can never be nil,Comparison isn't allowed

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code

```
func enteredByStr(S:String) -> String? {
    var healthactionplan : MyHealthActionPlanCondition

    if healthactionplan.addedBy != nil  {
        healthactionplan.addedBy = "System"
    } else {
        healthactionplan.addedBy = "Member"
    }
}
```

I have even followed this [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558933/why-is-the-return-value-of-string-addingpercentencoding-optional) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708636/swift-string-cant-be-nil-so-why-can-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwithallowedc). But still remains Unsolvable.Can anyone explain Why???

Comment: What does the declaration of `MyHealthActionPlanCondition` look like?

Comment: Among the other problems, you are not populating `healthactionplan`

Answer (score 5):

> Value of Type String can never be nil,Comparison isn't allowed

Error message is showing you everything

addedBy is a `String`. so check `isEmpty` on addedBy

```
 if healthactionplan.addedBy.isEmpty   {
    healthactionplan.addedBy = "System"
} else {
    healthactionplan.addedBy = "Member"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `healthactionplan.addedBy` is String as error said `Value of Type String can never be nil` that means you can't compare `String` with `nil` .. so try to check that string is empty or not

```
 if healthactionplan.addedBy.isEmpty { 
      healthactionplan.addedBy = "Member"
 } else {
      healthactionplan.addedBy = "System"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example the string cannot be nil.  I need to declare a string which can accept nil. So i have declared optional string:

```
var addedBy: String? = String()
```

After this i am able to check the nil value for the string.