# URL Query item from NSURLComponents are nill

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a `NSURL` URL will contain some escape character (Japanese)

```
    NSString* currentlocationbarString = @"mbos.help.jp/search?q=専門&pg=1"
NSString *escapedString = [currentlocationbarString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
```

> //url is mbos.help.jp%2Fsearch%3Fq=%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80&pg=1

When I create `NSURLComponents` and try to get query items it gives me nil.

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url
                                                resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
NSArray *queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems;
```

//here issue with queryItems

if anybody has solution to get query items please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is not with Unicode Characters, whenever you add encoding use proper character set for my case I was using following set`URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` it means your `NSURLComponents` only give encoding for your Host, to get correct `queryItems` use `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` like this way.

```
NSString* currentlocationbarString = @"mbos.help.jp/search?q=専門&pg=1"
NSString *escapedString = [currentlocationbarString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
```

So now you can get queryItems.

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url
                                            resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
NSArray *queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the characters 専門 that you use in your search string is **invalid Unicode** in the form of **unpaired UTF-16 surrogate chars**, and thus cannot be encoded by `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`, which therefore returns `nil`.
You can find an example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558934/1987726).
Apparently, you had to check for Japanese characters, if encoding is possible.
I must say, I did not expect that either!

Comment: character are valid, may be you can try with another characters.

Comment: I did not say that a character is invalid Unicode, I said that it does not have a paired UTF-16 character. In this case the encoding is not possible. Please check [this docu](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html). It says _U+10FFFF is the highest code point encodable to UTF-16 and the highest code point of the Unicode Character Set 6.0. The {U+DBFF, U+DFFF} surrogate pair is the last available pair._