# Swift - Encoding not supporting for some special characters

Tags: swift, encoding

I am using swift language 2.1.1

I am applying encoding mechanism on the string value. I used the following code,

let text = "-/:;.,?!'()&@*+=_~"

let encodedText = text!.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)

In my case, none of the characters are encoded.

May I have the solution on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
let encodedText = text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Comment: Hi Jinal. I followed this code. But still no luck. I didn't get the characters encoded

Comment: refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
let encodedText = text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet())
```