# Swift Weird Strings

Tags: swift

I am trying to use `NSURL` with string in this way:

```
var name = "Unknown Name"
let SearchString = "http://xxx?name=\(name)"
let SearchURL = NSURL(string: SearchString)
```

However, `SearchURL` become nil and throws an exception because there is a space between `"Unknown"` and `"Name"`

I Want to Add single quotes in the beginning and end of `name` variable but I can't because I did the following:

```
let SearchString = "http://xxx?name='\(name)'"
```

And when I track SearchString in the debugger I found it contains the following:

```
http://xxx?name=\'Unknown Name\'
```

and it throws the exception again.

How to remove these weird backslashes and use the single quotes only so I can use the `URL`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to encode the space in `name`. You can do this (and encode other special characters) by using `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` with the `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`

```
var name = "Unknown Name".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
...
```

Note the unsafeness of the `!` - if `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` returns `nil` there will be a crash

Comment: That solved my problem bro. And I don't know that there is something like that what will easy my work. Thanks.

Comment: No worries @FamousMaxy - if you command-click on `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` in Xcode you will see some other options for encoding different parts of a URL

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 7 there is a method [stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:) in NSString class.  That method returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all characters not in the specified set with percent encoded characters.

```
var originalString = "Unknown Name"
var escapedString = originalString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
println("escapedString: \(escapedString)")
```

URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet contains all allowed characters for URL query string.

Output:

```
Unknown%20Name
```

So changing the code to

```
var name = "Unknown Name"
var escapedName = name..stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
let SearchString = "http://xxx?name=\(escapedName)"
let SearchURL = NSURL(string: SearchString)
```

should do the trick