# Swift NSURL giving error on valid urls

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Look at this code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: physicst.image as String)
        if let url = url {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }else {
            print ("nill URL \(physicst.image)")
        }
```

so I have a string, and that string is a url, and I want to load it.

that code is in a table view cells, so it is being called for each cell.

as you see, i am checking if the url is nil or not, and if not, i am making a `print` statement. almost all the urls are not nil, exception the following ones (which are complemetly valid)

> [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Kai_Manne_Börje_Siegbahn.jpg?width=300](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Kai_Manne_B%C3%B6rje_Siegbahn.jpg?width=300)
>
> [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Виталий_Лазаревич_Гинзбург.jpg?width=300](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3.jpg?width=300)
>
> [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/赤崎記念研究館.jpg?width=300](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/%E8%B5%A4%E5%B4%8E%E8%A8%98%E5%BF%B5%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%E9%A4%A8.jpg?width=300)
>
> [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Kai_Manne_Börje_Siegbahn.jpg?width=300](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Kai_Manne_B%C3%B6rje_Siegbahn.jpg?width=300)
>
> [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/赤崎記念研究館.jpg?width=300](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/%E8%B5%A4%E5%B4%8E%E8%A8%98%E5%BF%B5%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%E9%A4%A8.jpg?width=300)

The first thing you may argue is to encode the url, and that is what I did like this:

```
var image = oneBinding["p"]!!["value"] as! NSString
                        image = image.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

but then even the urls that were working, stopped working. what i am missing please ?

#### Update

Here is the whole code of my UITableViewController (it is easy)

```
class PhysicistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var physicsts : [Physicst]?

    @IBOutlet var physicstsTableView: UITableView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadDataFromDBPedia()
    }

    func loadDataFromDBPedia()  {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql/"
        let query = "http://dbpedia.org&query=select * {?o  dbo:thumbnail ?p . ?o dbo:award dbr:Nobel_Prize_in_Physics}"
        url = url + "?default-graph-uri=" + query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
        url = url + "&format=JSON&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response ,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print ("\(error)")
            }
            if let response = response {
                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                print("Status code = \(statusCode)")
            }
            if let data = data  {
                do {
                    let jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
                    let binding = jsonResponse["results"]!!["bindings"] as! NSArray
                    for oneBinding in binding {
                        let name = oneBinding["o"]!!["value"] as! NSString
                        let image = oneBinding["p"]!!["value"] as! NSString
                        //image = image.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
                        let physicst = Physicst(image: image, name: name)
                        if self.physicsts == nil {
                            self.physicsts = [Physicst]()
                        }
                        self.physicsts!.append(physicst)
                    }
                    self.physicstsTableView.reloadData()
                }catch _ {
                    print ("not well json-formatted response")
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.physicsts == nil {
            return 0
        }else {
            return self.physicsts!.count
        }
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("physicstCell")! as UITableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        let physicst = self.physicsts![row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = physicst.name as String
        if (physicst.imageData == nil) {
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let url = NSURL(string: physicst.image as String)
            if let url = url {
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                    if let data = data {
                        let imageData = UIImage(data: data)
                        cell.imageView?.image = imageData
                        physicst.imageData = imageData
                        self.physicstsTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
            }else {
                print ("nill URL \(physicst.image)")
            }
        }else {
            cell.imageView?.image = physicst.imageData!
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: When working with async merhods dont forget to update the UI from the mainqueue

Comment: @TheRohanSanap there is no error, but the else statement is beign executed in the mentioned URLs, thought they are 100% valid urls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/2303865 Just use the image view extension

Comment: @LeoDabus yes but that has nothing to do with the problem in hand :)

Comment: Maybe App transport security issue

Comment: @LeoDabus well maybe that is a good alternative, but also I would like to know why the else statement is being executed in my code. Anyway, I am checking that answer, sounds good

Comment: If the problem is the url just add percent encoding

Comment: @LeoDabus no no not App things, I'm already downloading many images, i just have problems with the mentioned one, and I alreayd allowed all the connection in the plist file

Comment: @LeoDabus I added the encoding, as I showed you in the question, but then no of the urls, even the ones were working, works. I don't know why

Comment: can you paste the result of the conversion? `(print(image))`

Comment: @66o indeed i already did :) the urls i gave you in the question are the ones come from `print(image)`

Comment: sorry, what I mean is result of the percentEncoding

Answer (score 1):

The method you should use is

```
stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Taken from the playground:

```
NSURL(string:"http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Kai_Manne_Börje_Siegbahn.jpg?width=300".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)
```

Gives the result

```
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Kai_Manne_B%C3%B6rje_Siegbahn.jpg?width=300
```

Which is valid :)

Adapted to your code it gives:

```
let url = NSURL(string: (physicst.image as String).stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()!)
```

Beware of the forced unwrapping tho !

Comment: well interestinly the else statment wasn't called at all. but yet, your code is using a deprecated function. any alternative please ?

Comment: You need to use a different character set for each part of the url

Comment: Btw i think that method still available if you cast it to NSString

Comment: +1 for your efforts, if i get another answer with not depressed code, i will check, otherwise, i will accept your answer, appreciate the efforts

Comment: @sarah you are right, I edited the code. This is not perfect since we should split query string and host string, but it should work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` only contains this `"#%/<>?@\^`{|}

And your URL string contains `:` .. So make custom set for this

```
 let yourString = "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Kai_Manne_Börje_Siegbahn.jpg?width=300"
 let customSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"=\"#%/:<>?@\\^`{|}").invertedSet
 let finalString = yourString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(customSet)
```

For more info. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)

Comment: Your code neither makes the else execute, no makes me see the downloaded images.

Comment: @sarah this is same as allowedCharacterSet but just add some custom characters in set ... So url encode with custom character set ... I tried it ...it works for me ...

Comment: Plus one for your efforts, I'm trhying it