# How to correctly encode URL String

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, ios9, nsurlrequest

I already tried many many examples found here, but none of then works... the url is always nil ..

here the String :`http://www.tst.com.br/?Nr=OR(product.productType.displayName:Acess%C3%B3rios,product.productType.displayName:Outros%20Produtos)&Ns=sku.sortPriority|0&mi=hm_ger__mntop__FUT-outros_&cm_re=mntop-_-ger_-_-_FUT-outros_____&fc=menu&test=test`

```
            let urlSet = "http://www.tst.com.br/?Nr=OR(product.productType.displayName:Acess%C3%B3rios,product.productType.displayName:Outros%20Produtos)&Ns=sku.sortPriority|0&mi=hm_ger__mntop__FUT-outros_&cm_re=mntop-_-ger_-_-_FUT-outros_____&fc=menu&test=test"
        guard let url = NSURL(string: urlSet ?? "") else {
            return
        }
```

Should i decode and then encode again?

Already tried this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url), but dont work, the NSURL initialization is always nil

Comment: You have to explicitly allow `http://` URLs (as opposed  to `https://`). Have you done this? And are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: Sure, another requests works fine, but just some, with this encoding doesnt work

Comment: I don't believe the initializer for `NSURL` returns an optional. Try removing the guard statement. Your `nil` coalescing may be setting the value to an empty string.

Comment: @Ike10 the value for NSURL is always nil, if i dont use guard the request has no url..

Comment: Can you post some more code to give this code context? Like where it is and how the `urlSet` is determined?

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem :

```
extension String {
    func encodeString() -> String {
        let URLCombinedCharacterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet()
        URLCombinedCharacterSet.formUnionWithCharacterSet(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
        URLCombinedCharacterSet.addCharactersInString("@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%")
        let urlEncoded = self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(URLCombinedCharacterSet)
        return urlEncoded ?? self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is not a valid character in the URL string. You need to escape it:

```
let query = "Nr=OR(product.productType.displayName:Acess%C3%B3rios,product.productType.displayName:Outros%20Produtos)&Ns=sku.sortPriority|0&mi=hm_ger__mntop__FUT-outros_&cm_re=mntop-_-ger_-_-_FUT-outros_____&fc=menu&test=test"

let components = NSURLComponents()
components.scheme = "http"
components.host = "www.tst.com.br"
components.path = "/"
components.query = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

let url = components.URL!
```