# SWIFT parsing images from JSON

Tags: json, swift, image, parsing, url

In my application i want to parse JSON result that contains both text and images. the JSON result shows this string since the URL returned contains Arabic characters:

```
"Media_Photo" = "http://95.138.143.176/photos/FB/Ramy Ayach - \U0631\U0627\U0645\U064a \U0639\U064a\U0627\U0634/thumb/n583140_147657870534036_8903807944579055616.jpg";
```

This leads to error since it should be like:

```
http://95.138.143.176/photos/FB/Ramy Ayach - رامي عياش/thumb/n583140_147657870534036_8903807944579055616.jpg
```

how can i change this URL and be able to present the images in the UIImageView.

i tried this code:

```
let mediaPhotoUrl = newsInGroup?.mediaPhotoURL
    if let dataImageFornews = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: (mediaPhotoUrl)!)!){
        imageOfNews.image = UIImage(data: dataImageFornews)
    } else {
        imageOfNews.hidden = true
    }
```

but an error occurred :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Also the JSON response returns:

```
 "Media_Photo" = "<null>";
```

if no image. I handled this issue using this code:

```
 if media.valueForKey("Media_Photo") != nil {
    mediaPhoto = media.valueForKey("Media_Photo") as? String
    print("mediaphotoURL: \(mediaPhoto)")
    }
```

Is this the correct way?

```
 print("mediaphotoURL: \(mediaPhoto)")
```

gives

```
 mediaphotoURL: Optional("http://95.138.143.176/photos/FB/Ramy Ayach - رامي عياش/thumb/n583140_147657870534036_8903807944579055616.jpg")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get a working json response, I could imagine that arabic characters are special characters, so have a look here [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)
2. This error occures, because you try to work with an nil value

   ```
   if let mediaPhotoUrlNotNil:String = mediaPhotoUrl {
    if let mediaPhotoUrlToNSURL = NSURL(string: mediaPhotoUrlNotNil) {
     if let dataImageFornews = NSData(contentsOfURL: mediaPhotoUrlToNSURL) {
          //not nil
         } else {
          //nil
         }
       } else {
        //its nil
       }
      } else {
     //its nil
    }
   ```
3. Look here for a good way to get images from web:  [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)