# How to HTTP encode a URL string with special characters in iOS? (Swift/ObjC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have an url like this:

`http://mywebsite.net/User/UserInfo?key=123&userId=456&json=[{"UserName":"user@gmail.com","Password":"","Test":"item","projectId":"123","ItemsJSON":[{"Id":10,"Id2":0,"Quantity":5}]`

How do I make this url work in a NSURL. I will call `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL`

I tried doing:

```
let encodedString = sender.url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLUserAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

But I ended up with:
`http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.net%2FUser%2FUserInfo%3Fkey=123&userId=456&json=%5B%7B%22UserName%22%3A%22user%40gmail.com%22,%22Password%22%3A%22%22,%22Test%22%3A%22item%22,%22projectId%22%3A%22123%22,%22ItemsJSON%22%3A%5B%7B%22Id%22%3A10,%22Id2%22%3A0,%22Quantity%22%3A5%7D%5D`

Comment: Putting a password into the URL is a bad idea. It will be recorded in many log files and visible to people looking over your shoulder.

Comment: Don't mind the content. I won't be putting the password there. Just unimportant data.

Comment: normally you should only encode the end part ie after the "?". And you should escape for & character

Comment: Makes sense letme try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - encode URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)