# addingPercentEncoding works different in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, string, encoding

I have obj-C method that encodes String:

```
- (NSString *) encodeValue:(NSString*) unescaped{
    return [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
             [NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
}
```

input: `testswiftapppod://`

output: `testswiftapppod%3A%2F%2F`

I wrote the same method in Swift but got different output: `testswiftapppod:%2F%2F`

```
static func encodeValue(unescaped:String!) -> String{
   return unescaped.addingPercentEncoding(
        withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)!
}
```

**For some reason colon not converted**

How to fix this issue?

I use Xcode 8.3

**[EDIT]**

From Docs:

> // Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all
>   characters not in the allowedCharacters set with percent encoded
>   characters. UTF-8 encoding is used to determine the correct percent
>   encoded characters. Entire URL strings cannot be percent-encoded. This
>   method is intended to percent-encode an URL component or subcomponent
>   string, NOT the entire URL string. Any characters in allowedCharacters
>   outside of the 7-bit ASCII range are ignored.
>   - (nullable NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:(NSCharacterSet *)allowedCharacters NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);

Comment: It is strange that the Objective-C code behaves differently, but a colon *is* allowed in the host part of an URL, e.g. `http://myhost.com:myport/path`

Comment: As a colon is allowed in URL encoding. Just a question, have you tried something like "unescaped.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormData()" yet?

Comment: Also "testswiftapppod://" looks more like an URL scheme, why do you need to escape it at all?

Comment: @MartinR because I want to put it as argument to URL

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:**

This is probably undocumented but intended behavior. See [is `addingPercentEncoding` broken in Xcode 9 beta 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754996/is-addingpercentencoding-broken-in-xcode-9-beta-2) for more details.

---

This is a bug.

I went over different cases, it seems all Swift code works correctly. Note that `:` is allowed in URL host, therefore it should not be encoded and **the bug is in the Obj-C version**.

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet];    
NSLog(@"Colon is member: %@", [set characterIsMember:':'] ? @"true" : @"false"); // prints true
```

It's an interesting bug because if you add `":"` to the character set manually

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *set = [[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[set addCharactersInString:@":"];
```

Everything starts to work correctly.

Report it.

Note that when encoding for URL parameters, you shouldn't use `urlHostAllowed`. If possible, use `NSURLQuery` to build your `URL` instead. Neither of the predefined sets is actually suitable for URL encoding. You can start with `urlQueryAllowed` but you still have to remove some characters from it.

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39767536/669586) for a correct solution or for example the implementation in [Alamofire library](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/ab07523ee93527e79e99037f1a2d596b30689016/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L196).

Answer (score 1):

The desired output can be generated by:

```
func encodeValue(_ string: String) -> String? {
    guard let unescapedString = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ":/").inverted) else { return nil }

    return unescapedString
}

let encodedString = encodeValue("testswiftapppod://") // testswiftapppod%3A%2F%2F
```