# is `addingPercentEncoding` broken in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode, xcode9-beta

in Swift 3.x with Xcode 9 beta 2, using [`addingPercentEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1690785-addingpercentencoding) gives unexpected results. `CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed` always contains ":", so by definition of `addingPercentEncoding`, it should never escape it. Yet, using this code:

```
// always true
print(CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.contains(":"))
let myString = "info:hello world"
let escapedString = myString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!
print(escapedString)
```

I get those results:

#### cases where I get an undesirable behavior

- Xcode 9 beta 2, iOS 9.3
- Xcode 9 beta 2, iOS 11.0

  > true
  >   info%3Ahello%20world

#### cases where I get the expected behavior

- Xcode 9 beta 2, iOS 10.3.1
- Xcode 8.3.3, any iOS

  > true
  >   info:hello%20world

Is there any workaround to get a working implementation of `addingPercentEncoding` that will correctly respect the given `allowedCharacters`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently there is some undocumented magic done by `addingPercentEncoding` when the CharacterSet used as reference is an underlying NSCharacterSet class.

So to workaround this magic, you need to make your CharacterSet a pure Swift object. To do so, I'll create a copy (thanks Martin R!), so that the evil magic is gone:

```
let myString = "info:hello world"
let csCopy = CharacterSet(bitmapRepresentation: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.bitmapRepresentation)
let escapedString = myString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: csCopy)!
//always "info:hello%20world"
print(escapedString)
```

As an extension:

```
extension String {
    func safeAddingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters allowedCharacters: CharacterSet) -> String? {
        // using a copy to workaround magic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44754996/1033581
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(bitmapRepresentation: allowedCharacters.bitmapRepresentation)
        return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting observations! Note that also create a copy with `let cs = CharacterSet(bitmapRepresentation: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.bitmapRepresentation)`

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 10):

The reason that it is now percent escaping the `:` character is that `.urlPathAllowed` now strictly observes [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), which says in section 3.3, “Paths”:

> In addition, a URI reference (Section 4.1) may be a relative-path reference, in which case the first path segment cannot contain a colon (":") character.

Thus, the `:` is permitted in relative paths (which is what we're dealing with here), but simply not in the first component.

Consider:

```
let string = "foo:bar/baz:qux"
print(string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!)
```

That will, in conformance with RFC 3986, percent encode the `:` in the first component, but allow it unencoded in subsequent components:

```
foo%3Abar/baz:qux
```

This character set is not percent encoding solely on the basis of what characters are in the set, but is actually applying RFC 3986's relative path logic. But as Cœur said, if you need, you can bypass this logic by building your own character set with the same allowed characters as `.urlPathAllowed`, and that new character set will not apply this RFC 3986 logic.

Comment: Oh, that really explains the issues I have noticed in some other question... Wow, the documentation is really misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Calling iOS `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` replace only minimal set of special symbols `.urlQueryAllowed`: ("#%<>[]^`{|} ).
So, this situation may lead to problems on the server side, because some special symbols (for example +) cannot be processed by some kind of backend software.

We need to extend the set of special encoded symbols adding `+:@&,;=?/$`.
That characters I got by comparing encoded characters in Android Studio and iOS.

Use the function `convert(param: value)` and `components.percentEncodedQueryItems` instead `components.queryItems`.
Calling `components.queryItems` with custom function `convert` will lead to double encoding of urlQueryAllowed and error.

```
func makeRequest() async throws {

    let queryParams: [String: Any] = ["name": "Leanne Graham"]
    guard let baseUrl = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"),
          var components = URLComponents(url: baseUrl, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
        return
    }
    // Use `.percentEncodedQueryItems` instead of `.queryItems`! To avoid double encoding!
    components.percentEncodedQueryItems = queryParams.map { key, value in
        URLQueryItem(name: key, value: convert(param: value))
    }
    
    guard let url = components.url else { return }
    let result = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: URLRequest(url: url))
    print(result)
}
   
func convert(param: Any?) -> String? {
    
    if param == nil { return nil }
    
    switch param {
    case let boolValue as Bool: return "\(boolValue)"
    case let numberValue as NSNumber: return "\(numberValue)"
    case let stringValue as String:
        return stringValue.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowedExtended) ?? stringValue
    default:
        assertionFailure("Add a handler for the parameter type: \(type(of: param))")
        return ""
    }
}

extension CharacterSet {
    
    public static let urlQueryAllowedExtended: CharacterSet = {
        // urlQueryAllowed provide encoding for symbols: "\"#%<>[\]^`{|} "
        // We need extend it with following symbols: "+:@&,;=?/$"
        CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+:@&,;=?/$"))
    }()
}
```

[Example code with encoding on github with explanation and unit-test](https://github.com/IrixVol/EncodingSwift/tree/main)

Comment: Thank you, but `.urlQueryAllowedExtended` is [not defined](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=urlQueryAllowedExtended). I think it boils down to the line I wrote in my answer: `let csCopy = CharacterSet(bitmapRepresentation: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.bitmapRepresentation)`; in other words, you make your own character set, which solves the issues of unexpected behaviors coming from the native character sets.

Comment: Yes, I corrected my answer:
`CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+:@&,;=?/$"))`

And you can see all example on GitHub

Comment: Are you sure `subtracting` is the right choice to "extend"? I would use `union` personally, but I'm just human, so I can make mistakes.

Comment: Sure)) we need remove this symbols from all allowed) +:@&,;=?/$
This code from my large work project, and with Unit Test