# uiimageview is not Working using URLWithString:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsdata

```
_profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@".../images/Profile/Pratik Maniya Photo.jpg"]]];
```

I want to display image using the URL link in the code,
but there is not any result.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `NSDate`? Also, do not put theses 4 executions in one line. Separate each one, and check the value of each one to understand where the issue may lie.

Comment: Sorry for that, i tried that solution but no image display...i separate all execution, all have some data. but i can't get result...@Larme

Comment: url is right one...you can try. copy that URL and paste it in browser...u will get image...@Maddyヅヅ

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that in the browser, the url actually becomes https://safesocpgm.000webhostapp.com/images/Profile/Pratik%20Maniya%20Photo.jpg (with spaces escaped). There is a string function `addingPercentEncoding` that might be useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url

Comment: As pointed by Samantha, the URL is not valid. Just writing `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://safesocpgm.000webhostapp.com/images/Profile/Pratik Maniya Photo.jpg"];` gives nil, so I doubt that you tried separately and check the values. Escape the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the spaces symbols in url.

You can use:

```
stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]
```

Full code:

```
NSString *base_url = @"https://safesocpgm.000webhostapp.com/images/Profile/Pratik Maniya Photo.jpg";
NSString* encoded_url = [base_url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
_profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encoded_url]]];
```