# How to convert string to URL in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I want to convert below String to URL

`www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय`

I tried `let urlToSend = URL(string: "www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय")!` but it returns nil.

I'm getting that 'अक्षय' keyword from textField, it could be in any local language.

It works fine with English but not working with local language.

I used `let url = URL(string: "www.mydomain.com")?.appendingPathComponent("key=अक्षय")` it gives www.mydomain.com/key=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF

but now I want to 
`www.mydomain.com/key=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF` to `www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)

Comment: here is your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43682753/4415445

Comment: "www.mydomain.com/key=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF" is the valid url. Please explain what you mentioned "but now I want to www.mydomain.com/key=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF to www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय"... You could also check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48075721/5501940).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with URLs as strings, you should encode them to be valid as a URL; One of the most popular examples of encoding the URL is that the " " (space) would be encoded as "%20".

So in your case the encoded value of your url should be:

```
www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF
```

As you noticed the value of the `key` is changed

from: "अक्षय"

to:"%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF"

which will let the URL to be valid.

**How to:**

you could get the above result like this:

```
let string = "www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय"

if let encodedString  = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed), let url = URL(string: encodedString) {
    print(url) // www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF
}
```

Note that there is *optional binding* for both the encoded string and the url for the purpose of being safe.

**Decoding the URL:**

You could also returns to the original unencoded url (decoding it) like this:

```
let decodedString = "www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF"

if let unwrappedDecodedString = decodedString.removingPercentEncoding {
    print(unwrappedDecodedString) // www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय
}
```

Again, optional binding to be safe.

Comment: but I want to back 'www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF' to 'www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय'

Comment: @AkshayPhulare to make sure that I got it, you want to let "www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF" to be decoded to "www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय", is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

You need to encode the URL.

```
let urlString = "www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)
let url = URL(string: urlString!)

let decodedUrl = urlString?.removingPercentEncoding
```

Keep in mind that you shouldn't force unwrap URL's and strings, use if let or guard statements.

Comment: but I want to back 'www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7‌​%E0%A4%AF' to 'www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय'

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this thing:

```
    let strURL = "www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
    let url = URL(string: strURL!)
```

Or you can use:

```
let strURL = "www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)
let url = URL(string: strURL!)
```

Comment: but I want to back 'www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7‌​%E0%A4%AF' to 'www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय'

Comment: Just add strURL.removingPercentEncoding and again you will get your source string

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with percent encodings explicitly, you can also build the URL piece by piece, using `appendingPathComponent`:

```
let url = URL(string: "www.mydomain.com")?.appendingPathComponent("key=अक्षय")
// www.mydomain.com/key=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF
```

Comment: but I want to back 'www.mydomain.com%2Fkey=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7‌​%E0%A4%AF' to 'www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय'

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I want to back" exactly.

If you're talking about reversing the percent encodings, try `.removePercentEncoding` on `url.absoluteString`.

Answer (score 0):

Swift3.0

```
let baseUrl = "www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय" // base url

let encodedUrl : String! = baseUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) // remove the spaces in the url string

let typeUrl = URL(string: encodedUrl)! // convert the string into url

print(typeUrl)  // www.mydomain.com/key=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%AF
```

For Checking purpose

```
if let unwrappedDecodedString = encodedUrl.removingPercentEncoding {
        print(decodedString) // www.mydomain.com/key=अक्षय
}
```