# Configure URL with components swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to configure URL with components. Please take a look:

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?media=music&entity=song")
var queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "term", value: "crowded house")
let urlForce = urlComponents?.url!
```

When i try to look in playgrounds witch properties have been set, following properties as ok:

```
urlForce?.absoluteString
urlForce?.scheme
urlForce?.host
urlForce?.path
urlForce?.query
```

But `urlForce?.baseURL` is `nil`.
How to form url with all properties is set? I only know that following:

```
URL(string: "search", relativeTo: baseURL)
```

Set base url, but in that case i dont know how to add url components.

I want to form url with all properties are defined.

Comment: A base URL is only useful for a relative URL. You are creating an absolute URL so there is no point to a base URL.

Comment: @rmaddy i want url that have base url and also want to add query items to it.

Comment: scheme = "https", host = "itunes.apple.com", path = "\search" and add your query items. check the duplicate link above

Comment: @LeoDabus question is - how to add query item?

Comment: check my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668198/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks Leo your answer is correct.

Comment: you are welcome