# Waze doesn't load navigation from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, openurl, waze

I integrated Waze into my Swift app, but when I click on the button, Waze opens but nothing happens with the navigation. I juste see the app and that's all, instead of launching the navigation.

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func openWazeAction(_ sender: Any) {
    // open waze
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {
        let urlStr = String(format: "waze://ul?ll=%f,%f&navigate=yes", (selectedBorne?.location?.x)!, (selectedBorne?.location?.y)!)

        print(urlStr)

        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
    }
}
```

The `print(urlStr)` returns the right URL: `waze://ul?ll=48.792914,2.366290&navigate=yes`, but nothing happens in the Waze app.

*(I put the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the Info.plist file.)*

What is wrong here?

Comment: Does it work with `let urlString = https://waze.com:/ul?ll=48.792914,2.366290&navigate=yes` Does something happen? Source: https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/

Comment: It opens a Safari view, I think they made a mistake in their documentation about that, because it is not logic to verify if `waze://` exists, then open `https://` url.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The [Waze documentation](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/#ios-example) gives wrong information because their iOS example doesn't open the Waze app as it should be. It opens Safari on mobile and then we need to click on a link to open Waze.

The correct link is:

```
waze://?ll={latitude},{longitude}&navigate=yes
```

I needed to remove `ul` in the URL.

---

### Swift

```
func navigateTo(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {
        // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
        let urlStr = String(format: "waze://?ll=%f,%f&navigate=yes", latitude, longitude)
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!)
    } else {
        // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
    }
}
```

---

### Objective-C

```
(void) navigateToLatitude:(double)latitude longitude:(double)longitude
{
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
    canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"waze://"]]) {
      // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
      NSString *urlStr =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"waze://?ll=%f,%f&navigate=yes",
        latitude, longitude];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
  } else {
    // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
      URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106"]];
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great, but what if I want to navigate by search term and not long/lat?

Comment: You should encode your search term (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39767536/6488573)) and then pass it like that in your URL: `waze://?q=` your search term.

Comment: Trying this `"waze://?q=19+Hatzfira+st,+Jerusalem,+Israel"
`, opens Waze but without navigation.

Comment: You should convert your search term into latitude and longitude using GeoCode

Comment: You can try this:

   `query = 'gas station Israel'`
     `waze://?q=query`

it's work for me, and if if the user doesn't have waze on the device you can open on browser like this:
`https://waze.com/ul?q=${query}`

Comment: if i want to pass source and destination location then how can i pass ?

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer was not working for me, i was running the app on my device with waze installed and it always opened the appstore. With this code it opens waze if it is installed and it opens the appstore if not.

```
let urlStr = String(format: "waze://?ll=%f,%f&navigate=yes", latitude, longitude)
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!) { didOpen in
        
        if !didOpen {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer! Totally worked for me. Thanks, Mario! You saved me a ton of time!