# Swift 4 Escape ampersand in NSURLComponents

Tags: ios, swift

I am using NSURLComponents in Swift 4 like so:

```
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice + "?PDFFile=" + PDFFile);
```

My String PDFFile looks like this:

Tom & Jane PDF.pdf

My question is how do I escape the ampersand in NSURLComponents?

This is what I get:

```
ANC%2520%26%2520SHO%2520-%2520Laundry%2520Closets%2520to%2520be%2520Checked.pdf
```

But this is what I need:

```
ANC+%26+SHO+-+Laundry+Closets+to+be+Checked.pdf
```

Comment: That's not how you use URLComponents. Add the query using the provided API.

Comment: @rmaddy example?

Comment: Not one of the solution in the so called question I duplicated work at all

Comment: Sure they do. Try this specific one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668198/1226963

Comment: That 100% did not work, the string im trying to encode comes out like this `ANC%2520%26%2520SHO%2520-%2520Laundry%2520Closets%2520to%2520be%2520Checked.pdf` when I need it like this `ANC+%26+SHO+-+Laundry+Closets+to+be+Checked.pdf`

Comment: Since you aren't showing how you get that, no one can help.