# SWIFT Translator App

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-api

I create translator using Yandex api.
I use this function:

```
func getTranslate(text: String, lang: String, completion: @escaping (Translation?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: translateUrl + "?key=\(key)&text=\(text)&lang=\(lang)&format=plain&options=1") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        do {
            let translation = try JSONDecoder().decode(Translation.self, from: data)
            completion(translation)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

But if I enter in "Text" more one word translation is not carried out.

The API documentation says:

"For the source code, be sure to use URL-encoding."

I suspect that my problem is related to the fact that I just use the text, not coding it in any way.
How can this problem be solved?

api documentation
https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/reference/detect-docpage/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's highly recommended to use `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem`, it handles URL encoding implicitly

```
guard var components = URLComponents(string: translateUrl) else { return }
components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: key),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: text),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "lang", value: lang),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "format", value: "plain"),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "options", value: String(1))]
var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
```