# How can I convert the string to URL which include a ? in the string by Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, swift4

As the title, I am using Google Places API, the URL has a question mark, when I send a request, it will become %3F, how can I modify my code by Swift 4.2??

I found a lot of information but they were using Swift 2 or 3, so it is unavailable for me!

**UPDATE** my code

```
let urlString = "\(GOOGLE_MAP_API_BASEURL)key=\(GMS_HTTP_KEY)&input=\(keyword)&sessiontoken=\(ver4uuid!)"
        print(urlString)
        if let encodedString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics
            .union(CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed)
            .union(CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)) {
            print("encodedString: \(encodedString)")
```

Comment: Show us your code and we can advise how to fix it. Almost nothing has change in how URL encoding works though.

Comment: @Sulthan I have updated my code, thanks!

Comment: You are supposed to urlEncode only the keyword. Nothing else needs encoding. And you *cannot* encode the whole `urlString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to encode only the query parameters (although probably only `keyword` actually needs encoding), not the whole URL.

```
func urlEncode(_ string: String) -> String {
    var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
    allowed.remove(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]")
    return string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed) ?? ""
)

let urlString = "\(GOOGLE_MAP_API_BASEURL)key=\(urlEncode(GMS_HTTP_KEY))&input=\(urlEncode(keyword))&sessiontoken=\(urlEncode(ver4uuid!))"
print(urlString)
```

Also see [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url) about the correct way to encode URL parameters.

Comment: If I have a UTF8 character, can I use this method as well?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I highly recommend to use `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem` which handles the percent escaping very smoothly.

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: GOOGLE_MAP_API_BASEURL)!
let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: GMS_HTTP_KEY),
                  URLQueryItem(name: "input", value: keyword),
                  URLQueryItem(name: "sessiontoken", value: ver4uuid!)]
urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
let url = urlComponents.url!
```