# Avoid percent encoding of host in URLComponents

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlcomponents

Using `URLComponents`, is there a way to avoid percent encoding of host?

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "endpoint.com/v1/api.php?"
// ends up as https://endpoint.com%2Fv1%2Fapi.php%3F? but I want it to stay as https://endpoint.com/v1/api.php?
```

This question is about **avoiding** encoding, not **adding** encoding as the question linked as duplicate states.

Comment: Duplicate question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url

Comment: @Aman, then vote to close and specify the duplicate question there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"/v1/api.php" is not part of the `host`, but rather the `path`.

Use this:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "endpoint.com"
components.path = "/v1/api.php"
```