# FileManager changes given URL path

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager, file-manager

I want to remove a file. For it, I have the `url`. Its `url.absoluteString` is:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/UUID/Library/Caches/someLocation/CexRlA-L:2258
```

The file exists because

```
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) == true
```

But doing

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
```

fails with error:

```
Failed to remove "CexRlA-L/2258"
```

FileManager changes the `:` in the filename (`CexRlA-L:2258`) to `/`. So `CexRlA-L` becomes treated as a folder and it of course does not exist.

I have not managed to reproduce locally, but it happens often to our users. Any pointers on what may be going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't by any chance use [`displayName(atPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1409751-displayname) ? *That* function would translate a colon to a slash. I am not aware that any other FileManager function does such a translation implicitly.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I do `let url = folderURL?.appendingPathComponent("CexRlA-L:2258")` and before I run `FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)`. folderURL is created by appending `Library`, `Caches` and `someLocation` to the shared file URL `FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com...")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24552028/8294374