# Encode URL in Swift 5

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

What's the most concise way to encode URL in Swift?

I have

```
let request_url = URL(string:"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=dca0aa44807a0bc05ed51c6a85472341&q="+"New York")
```

How can i add + instead of a space between New and York through some simple method available in swift?

Comment: `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)

Comment: yes. We can do string manipulation. But how can we use some method to automatically do this for us?
+ sign was just an example. We have other things in the URL as well.Can we do this through some URL builder?

Comment: @fl034 No It doesn't help.
I need a simple method
Which takes a string URL and converts it into a formatted URL (for example Adding + sign instead of spaces)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to encode spaces as `+` and encode other special characters correctly as well. 
So this approach uses the native function [`addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) that translates a sspaces to `%20`. Afterwards we replace all occurrences of `%20` with a `+`.

```
extension URL {
    init?(encoding string: String) {
        let encodedString = string
            .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)                
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: "+")                
        guard let encodedString != nil else { return nil }
        self.init(string: encodedString!)
    }
}
```

This is encapsulated in an `URL` init function, so you can use it like this:

```
let requestUrl = URL(encoding: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=dca0aa44807a0bc05ed51c6a85472341&q="+"New York")
```