# c# decryption from swift encryption

Tags: c#

In swift I wrote this code to encrypt a string

```
func Encrypt2(_ input:String)->String?{
    let key = "123456abcdefcdhs"
    do{
        let encrypted: Array<UInt8> = try AES(key: key, iv: key, padding: .pkcs5).encrypt(Array(input.utf8))
        return encrypted.toBase64()?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
    }catch{

    }
    return nil
}
```

And in c# the code for decryption is this

```
string key = "123456abcdefcdhs";
            RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
            rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
            byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
            byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
            int len = pwdBytes.Length;
            if (len > keyBytes.Length)
            {
                len = keyBytes.Length;
            }
            Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
            rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
            rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
            byte[] plainText = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
```

Encrytion works fine but when it comes to c# decryption...give me an error saying
base64 length.
I tried changing the .pkcs5 to .pkcs7 but still doesn't work.
whats wrong with the code?

The base64 string is --> aMtLgvWQOguK+GPbGT/Jxw==
sometimes the string is --> aMtLgvWQOguK GPbGT/Jxw==

Comment: At a guess Swift uses a modified base64 encoding. If you showed the base64 it might help. C# expects base64 using `+`, `/` and, for padding, `=`.  Modified base64 might instead use `-` and `_` and not include any padding, for example. See the [base64 wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history) for more info.

Comment: just added the base64

Comment: That's the base64 as output from Swift, right? Because I have no issues converting that to `byte[]` in C# using the `Convert.FromBase64String` method.

Comment: yes its from swift code..hmm...is it my c# code thats wrong? it keeps giving me Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.' this as an error

Comment: The base64 you've provided [doesn't repro the problem though](https://rextester.com/CSHM94929). That's the only place that could throw that exception, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: the base64 sometimes changes removing +

Comment: OK, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that you're posting this to a web server, since `+` can be interpreted the same as space (also encoded as `%20`). You should URL encode your base64 before sending it to a server in the URL. Specifically, `+` should be `%2B`, `/` should be `%2F`, and `=` should be `%3D`. It seems there is a [Swift method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url) for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211522/discussion-between-bongjae-jeong-and-john).