# GET Device Name in Swift WKWebview

Tags: ios, get, swift5, uidevice

How can i get the device name in swift5 and send it with the wkwebview url. If i print the name i get the model name but with the following code i get the error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
 let name = UIDevice.current.name
 let url = URL(string: "mydomain/index.php?token=\(token ?? "")&model=\(name)")!
 webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

I need the device name and token to store in a mysql database.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try to unwrap (! operator at the end of 2nd line) unsafe expression. URL constructor doesn't recognize the string you pass as string: parameter as valid url. it returns nil and causes fatal error. try to refactor your code to make it more safe:

```
let urlStr = "mydomain/index.php?token=\(token ?? "")&model=\(name)"
print("trying to load url \(urlStr)")
if let url = URL(string: urlStr) {
   webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

UPDATE:
followed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url) SO question the code must be slightly refactored:

```
let urlStr = "mydomain/index.php?token=\(token ?? "")&model=\(name)"
print("trying to load url \(urlStr)")
if let url = URL(string: urlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)) {
   webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Comment: I don't have the error anymore, but webview don't load the URL

Comment: your url is not valid. you should specify full url like http ://example.com/index.php?token=\(token ?? "")&model=\(name)

Comment: mydomain is just an example. In my code is the full url.

Comment: Still not loading the url. Print result is:  WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
https://myurl/index.php?token=ePtIACpD_0FthMoi2Y7bKi:APA91bGzCs226WKrFySV2ef7ZZZecEE2DSJ1DEC_mofYyVLtHvyaBZrqyfEPkhYTQ8-w5r1bkzQhpOQ8g-3dADYWk_W8l3ffr2B_8CX40JzryMtXEqZdfx7PFU__C8aD_-EzbvVomrR7&model=Simulator iPhone12,5

Comment: ah, you see? space character in "Simulator iPhone12,5" probably breaks the url

Comment: I replaced urlHostAllowed with urlQueryAllowed and now it,s ok. Thank you!