# How do I pass a URL with multiple query parameters in to email body using mailto in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Consider:

```
let body =  "Some text: www.google.co.in?q=1&q2=sdsdsds"
let urlString = "mailto:\(toEmail)?subject=\(subject.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!)&body=\(body.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!)"
```

Whenever the mail client opens, it strips the second parameter `&q2=sdsdsds.`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents). Here is some code:

```swift
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "your URL string without queries")
urlComponents?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "subject", value: subject)]
```

Also checkout [this article by Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/constructing-urls-in-swift/).

Comment: Can you show me a working example using the above? I tried, the ref link but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check-out the documentation or sundell's article link I provided? I've used it everywhere, also have my own library for service calls which use `urlComponents` effectively.

Comment: @HemantBavle Also note, url's can't contain spaces, I hope you know this should be urlEncoded to `%20` here is the link for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url

Comment: I have tried all of encoding stuff, nothing works, when the email client opens, I do not see the query params except the one after question mark.