# Getting the error 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' when using index to access the array elements

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am calling the API service from my viewController using a private function.

```
private func updateCells() -> Void {
    let cities: [String] = ["New York", "London", "Tokyo", "Toronto", "Sydney", "Paris"]
    
    for cityName in cities {
        print(cityName)
        queryService.getSearchResults(cityName: cityName){results, errorMessage in
            
            if let results = results{
                self.myCity = results
                self.CityGrid.reloadData()
                self.list.append(results)
                print("Test -> name: \(results.name)")
                print("Test -> description: \(results.description)")
                print("Test -> currentTemp: \(Int(results.currentTemperature))")
                print(self.list[0])
                
            }
            
            if !errorMessage.isEmpty {
              print("Search error: " + errorMessage)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the QueryService class function to handle the API calls.

```
func getSearchResults(cityName: String, completion: @escaping QueryResult) {
    
    dataTask?.cancel()
    
    let url = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(cityName)&units=metric&appid=zezfac1ecbe0511f1ac192add4ff112e")!
  
    
    dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
        
        
        defer {
            self?.dataTask = nil
        }
        
        if let error = error {
            self?.errorMessage += "Default Task Error: " + error.localizedDescription + "\n"
        } else if
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode == 200 {
            
            self?.updateRestults(data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(self?.location, self?.errorMessage ?? "")
            }
        }
        else if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                res.statusCode == 404{
            self?.errorMessage = "City Not Found"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                completion(self?.location, self?.errorMessage ?? "Not Found")
            }
            
            //print("City Not found")
        }
    }
    dataTask?.resume()
}
```

[image: error message picture]

But I get the error Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. But if I use a hard-coded string it works fine. What am I doing wrong here? Since the cities array is of type String,

Comment: Can you also mention the line of crash?

Comment: let url = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(cityName)&units=metric&appid=zezfac1ecbe0511f1ac192add4ff112e")!

Comment: You'll probably need to encode the URL first: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24551816/14351818

Comment: You said hardcoded value works, can you show the difference in code for both cases? Currently what you have in above code for URL, is it hardcoded?

Comment: Case - 1: Hardcoded value this works fine.                                                                                                    queryService.getSearchResults(cityName: "London"){results, errorMessage in                                     Case - 2                
queryService.getSearchResults(cityName: cityName){results, errorMessage in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the string `"New York"` which has spaces in it, and those spaces are put directly into the URL, which causes the initialization of the URL to fail. Spaces are not valid in URLs without first encoding them to `%20`.

You should change the line `let cities: [String] = ...` to `var cities: [String] = ...` and add this right line underneath it:

`cities = cities.map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20") }`

This will replace every space in the city names with a `%20` and store it back into the variable `cities`.

Comment: Getting the same error after adding the lines you mentioned as well as tried the addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) method as well

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't seem to replicate the error with that line added. Is the function called anywhere else in the program without encoding any invalid characters?

Comment: I did some research and found out that the OpenWeatherMap API uses the '+' sign for the blank spaces. So the replacingOccurances(of:  " ", with: "+") method worked for me.