# Convert String With Special Symbols like (|, &, -) into Url in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, urlencode

I'm getting stuck with an issue to convert a string into url. The problem is the string containing some special symbols like &, | , -, # etc. I try to use different encoding methods on it but unable to convert it into url. I try to encode string that return a valid string like the symbols converted into %a etc. but again when I try to convert this encoded string to url getting same string (with special character) in return.

I have shared a sample string. Please let me know what encoding or conversion method i can use to convert this string into url.

Sample String:
[http://qc.singlevendor.4livedemo.com/yokart/product/image/176/176|11|133|/330-440-webp?t=1623042841](http://qc.singlevendor.4livedemo.com/yokart/product/image/176/176%7C11%7C133%7C/330-440-webp?t=1623042841)

Note: If I paste the same url in browser it apply an encoding method on url and open the correct image

Thanks in advance

Comment: @matt, Please check in the above shared string "176|11|133|" this part of the string contains some symbols "|" that cause the issue.

Comment: @user14588583 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668198/2303865

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
let input = "http://qc.singlevendor.4livedemo.com/yokart/product/image/176/176|11|133|/330-440-webp?t=1623042841"

let output = input.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
print(output)

let expected = "http://qc.singlevendor.4livedemo.com/yokart/product/image/176/176%7C11%7C133%7C/330-440-webp?t=1623042841"
print(output == expected)
```