# I can't use Viber on ios to share content in other languages

Tags: ios, viber

I can't share Burmese, but I can share English
NSString * const viberScheme = @"viber://forward?text=မဂ်လာပါဂိမ်းကစားကြမယ်";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:viberScheme]];

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works fine. Maybe check the quotation marks in the url-schema you used?
You can encode the text and it will work also.

Like

viber://forward?text="%E1%80%99%E1%80%82%E1%80%BA%E1%80%9C%E1%80%AC%E1%80%95%E1%80%AB%E1%80%82%E1%80%AD%E1%80%99%E1%80%BA%E1%80%B8%E1%80%80%E1%80%85%E1%80%AC%E1%80%B8%E1%80%80%E1%80%BC%E1%80%99%E1%80%9A%E1%80%BA"