# How to deal with special URL characters in Swift?

Tags: swift, url, urlencode, urldecode

I have sample URL with following string: `https://hello.com/%23/search%3Ftext=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82`

If we decode that, we would get `https://hello.com/#/search?text=привет`.

So, we notice that `#`, `?` and Cyrillic work gets encoded. The web service does not support encoding `#` and `?`, but understands encoded cyrrilic word. It means that I should transform above URL to this: `https://hello.com/#/search?text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82`

How to do that in Swift? Of course, I can simple replace some characters, but it is not maintainable solution because I don't know all characters that can create problem. So, how to solve this? First of all, I can use `removePercentEncoding` that returns clean string without any encoding.

`"https://hello.com/%23/search%3Ftext=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82".removePercentEncoding` returns my clean string `https://hello.com/#/search?text=привет`. But that one is not convertible to `URL` (it just returns nil). So, I should encode it again. I can use `"https://hello.com/#/search?text=привет".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)`, but it returns `https://hello.com/%23/search?text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82`. It is almost what I want, but not exactly. I can replace `%23` with `#` sign and get desired result but this solution is not maintainable. So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Important: the accepted answer from the link is _not_ how you should compose a URL!  Instead, use [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents). There is also a correct answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668198/465677. Also, there are literally hundreds of these kind of questions. All issues can be solved with URLComponents, provided client _and_ server obeying the rules stated in the related [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper # sign is still encoded in url even after using URLComponents. How to avoid that?

Comment: Using URLComponents to _compose_ your URL out from the given parts. If you not have noticed, your given URL string is likely not what you want to have: 
scheme: https,
host: "hello.com",
path: "/#/search?text=привет",
query: nil,
fragment: nil