# Why does this URL scheme return nil?

Tags: swift

```
let midoriURL = URL(string: "kotoba://dictionary?word=犬")!
```

I am trying to open a third-party app, Imiwa, and search for a word. If I open that URL in Safari, it will successfully go to the app and open the search result. But trying to make this into a URL in Swift, it is not successfully creating a URL.

Comment: `犬` may be causing your issues, it may need to be encoded

Comment: I tried to encode the character using `URLComponents`, but it caused a crash.  I then tried `"犬".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)` and while this works, it might not produce the result you're after

Comment: [This tool](https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/rawurlencode) gives the proper encoding of the hiragana character as %E7%8A%AC, so `"kotoba://dictionary?word=%E7%8A%AC"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` will only support ASCII characters, unicode characters will need to be encoded.

After a bit of googling and playing around, I was able to get...

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "kotoba"
components.host = "dictionary"
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "word", value: "犬")
components.queryItems = [queryItem]
let url = components.url
```

to produce `Optional(kotoba://dictionary?word=%E7%8A%AC)` (you can unwrap it)

*(credit to [Swift - encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url))*

In my testing I also tried using `let escapedString = "犬".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)` which also produced `"%E7%8A%AC"`

I've not tried opening the `URL`, but at least it's no longer `nil`

Comment: Any reason I should be using .urlHostAllowed instead of .urlQueryAllowed?

Comment: @alamodey I copied and pasted it and it worked, but I guess `.urlQueryAllowed` would probably be more suitable