# iOS 10 MKMapItem check if maps app installed

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm using this code to get directions to some location by native iOS maps

```
let item = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.customCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
if !MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [item], launchOptions: [ MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]) {
    print("error opening maps")
}
```

Is it possible to check if native Apple Maps app is available (it is possible to "remove" it from desktop in iOS 10+)? I would want to hide "Get directions" button instead of letting user click on it and get error.

Comment: Not possible to check?

Comment: There is already answered in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603120/how-to-check-if-apple-maps-is-installed . You can check if apple map is installed or not using UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "maps://")!) .